# How to calculate how many bacteria in each group are resistant to an antibiotic

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am attempting to count instances of resistance to 1 or 1+ antibiotics under certain conditions. Here is an example of what what my spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

For each drug "1" indicates resistance and "0" indicates sensitivity.

If I wanted to determine the number of bacteria in Group A that are resistant to only one antibiotic how would I do this? Or if I wanted to find how many bacteria in Group A are resistant to 1 or more antibiotics?

I've been struggling with this one for awhile so if anyone could point me in the right direction I would sure appreciate it.

Ideally my output would look like this

[image]

Comment: Why not put the sum of columns C:E in column F and then use `COUNTIF`? By the way -- what does the `9` in column E represent?

Comment: Sorry that is another part of my data, the 9 means Not Tested so any bacteria with a 9 in one of the drug columns would need to be excluded.

Comment: I could definitely do it the way you suggested but I was hoping for a 'cleaner' solution. The above data is part of a much larger spreadsheet with many columns so I would prefer to avoid adding extra columns if at all possible. The output number of bacteria resistant to 1 and 1+ antibiotics for Group A and B is supposed to be in a separate table. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: VBA would give a clean solution. Making a pivot table out of the data would be a natural non-VBA solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are array formulas. You MUST use Ctrl-Shift-Enter to enter these formulas, and Excel will magically insert curly braces (you cannot insert them yourself).

For exactly 1 resistance, enter into I2 as I have the setup in the pic below :

`=SUM(($B$2:$B$11=$H2)*IF(MMULT($C$2:$E$11, TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($C$1:$E$1)^0))=1, 1, 0))` for typeA.

Drag the formula down to get type B as in my set up.

`=SUM(($B$2:$B$11=$H3)*IF(MMULT($C$2:$E$11, TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($C$1:$E$1)^0))=1, 1, 0))`

For more than 1 resistance, in J2, use:

`=SUM(($B$2:$B$11=$H2)*IF(MMULT($C$2:$E$11, TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($C$1:$E$1)^0))>1, 1, 0)*(MMULT(IF($C$2:$E$11=9, 0, 1), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($C$1:$E$1)^0))= COLUMNS($C$1:$E$1)))`

Again, drag the formula down to get typeB...

[image]

Note that there are only ever three cell ranges/areas which you need to input into the formulas (albeit in several spots).

1. The data range for the type column
2. The data area for the resistance test results
3. The column headers for the drugs(should be the same width as the test results area).

If you set up named ranges for these areas, then you could put the named range into the formulas, and never have to amend the formula range arguments when the data ranges change size. But that's another point...

***Edit for explanation:***
If you evaluate formula parts, you might see something like this(for the image I provided)
    `=SUM(({TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE})*IF(MMULT({1,0,0;1,9,1;0,1,1;9,1,0;1,0,1;1,1,0;9,1,1;0,1,9;0,1,1;1,1,0},{1;1;1})>1, 1, 0)*(MMULT({1,1,1;1,0,1;1,1,1;0,1,1;1,1,1;1,1,1;0,1,1;1,1,0;1,1,1;1,1,1},{1;1;1})= 3))`

True or false evaluates as 1 or 0 when multiplied.

The effect of the '^0' is to turn each non-zero number in the resultant arrays into a '1'. This allows matrix multiplication to take place on the datarange to spit out column vectors.

`TRANSPOSE({3,4,5}^0)` becomes: `TRANSPOSE({1,1,1})`, which then becomes this: `{1;1;1}`. Notice the difference between commas and semicolons - this means a 1x3 vector is transposed into a 3x1 vector. Then you can use that as the second parameter into matrix multiplication with a 10x3 matrix(thats the dataset in our case).

The output of that MMULT is a 10x1 column vector representing some output.

The first MMULT is used to test if the row Total of any bacteria is > 1. The second MMULT is used to see if all the row entries for any bacteria are <> 9.

A similar thing is done for the case for Exactly One. The MMULT function is used once to determine if the row total for a bacterium is exactly 1.

Comment: I apologize for what is probably a silly question, your formulas work great, I just need to understand exactly what is going on so that I can do this for myself in the future. What does the ^0 do? Also at the end of the resistant to 1 antibiotic formula what does the =1 ,1 ,0 represent? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column for "Resistance Count" and use `=COUNTIF(B2:D2,">=1")` for cell E2 and fill down. Then you can filter the table by Type or Resistance Count. Use `SUBTOTAL` to count the filtered rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

1) Create an additional column (named "Count") to the right of your table with the count of 1s in each bacteria row. The formula is: `=COUNTIF(C2:E5, "1")`

2) Create another column (named "Resistance")to the right of your table with a nested IF statement. The formula is: `=IF(F2=1,"Resistant to 1",IF(F2=0,"Resistant to 0","Resistant to More than 1"))`

3) Create a Pivot Table with this Data. Put "Resistance" in the Columns Field, "Type" in the Rows Field, and "Sum of Count" in the Values field.

This should give you exactly what you want.